# Como fazer um counter contar incrementos por instância?

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar um `Counter` em Python com as seguintes propriedades:

1. `Counter(name)`: cria um contador chamado name
2. `increment`: aumenta o contador em 1 unidade
3. `tally`: número de incrementos desde a criação
4. `to_string`: representação em string

Isso foi o que tentei até agora:

```py
#flips.py
import sys
import numpy as np

iterations = int(sys.argv[1])

def counted(function):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.calls+=1
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.calls = 0
    return wrapped


class Counter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

    @counted
    def increment(self):
        pass

    def tally(self):
        return self.increment.calls

    def to_string(self):
        return self.name

heads = Counter(name='heads')
tails = Counter(name='tails')

for _ in range(iterations):
    result=np.random.binomial(1,0.75)
    if result==0:
        heads.increment()
    else:
        tails.increment()

print(heads.tally(), "heads")
print(tails.tally(), "tails")

delta = heads.tally()-tails.tally()

print(f'delta: {delta}')
```

Gostaria que esse programa retorna-se:

```bsh
python flips.py 10

7 heads
3 tails
delta:4
```

Mas, na verdade, obtenho esse resultado:

```
10 heads
10 tails
delta: 0
```

Obviamente, o método `increment` está sendo contado todas as vezes que ele é chamado *independente* de qual instância chama ele. Como faço para a contagem do método `increment` seja específico por instância?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro vamos modificar um pouco o seu código para entender melhor o que acontece:

```
def counted(function):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.calls+=1
        print('wrap', id(wrapped), 'calls=', wrapped.calls)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.calls = 0
    print('wrapping', function)
    return wrapped
```

E vou criar dois contadores:

```
print('criando counters')
c1 = Counter('a')
c2 = Counter('b')
print('incrementando')
c1.increment()
c2.increment()
print(c2.tally())
```

A saída será:

```
wrapping <function Counter.increment at 0x148a9cf5fe18>
criando counters
incrementando
wrap 22585571409024 calls= 1
wrap 22585571409024 calls= 2
2
```

Claro que os ids mudarão a cada execução, mas o importante é o que o *decorator* só roda uma vez, quando a classe é criada. Isso quer dizer que o contador só é zerado neste momento.

Ao incrementar, usa-se o mesmo método decorado (o `wrapped`, veja que o id é o mesmo nas duas linhas: `wrap 22585571409024`). Como já dito, o id varia a cada execução, mas o importante é que as duas linhas exibem o mesmo valor.

Sendo assim, o mesmo contador sempre é incrementado, mesmo que sejam chamados em instâncias diferentes de `Counter`, pois o `wrapped` é o mesmo para ambas (e portanto o contador também).

Se cada contador deve ser independente, então esqueça o *decorator*. O mais simples é que cada `Counter` faça sua própria contagem:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cont = 0 # cada Counter tem seu próprio contador
 
    def increment(self):
        self.cont += 1 # incrementa o próprio contador (não interfere nos demais)
 
    def tally(self):
        return self.cont # retorna o contador
```

Assim cada `Counter` tem seu próprio contador, que não interfere nas demais instâncias.

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas para implementar o método `to_string`, uma alternativa melhor é sobrescrever o [método especial `__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Assim ele já converte a instância para string se você imprimir (`print(instancia_de_counter)`), por exemplo.